# Google Visualization Chartwrapper Selecting Chart Element

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I can't seem to get the value of a piechart slice when selected. Here is my code:

```
var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper( {
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: saleTypes,
    options: { 
        title: 'Types of Sale',
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 18
        },
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '75%' },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
} );

google.visualization.events.addListener( pieChart, 'ready', onReady );

function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = pieChart.getChart().getSelection()[0];
    if ( selectedItem ) {
        var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
        alert('The user selected ' + value);
    }
}

function onReady() {
   google.visualization.events.addListener( pieChart.getChart(), 'select', selectHandler );
}

pieChartViolationTypes.draw();
```

I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Invalid row index undefined. Should be in the range [0-112]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the chart's data table to access values within the select handler...

`pieChart.getDataTable().getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);`

not sure where `data` is defined but if the chart is bound to a filter,
then need to use the current data the chart is working with...

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = pieChart.getChart().getSelection()[0];
    if ( selectedItem ) {
        var value = pieChart.getDataTable().getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
        alert('The user selected ' + value);
    }
}
```

note: pie charts may only have one series column and return `null` for the column index in `getSelection`

**EDIT**

if a view is also applied on the chart,
use the selection to get the row index from `view.rows`

```
pieChart.getView().rows[selectedItem.row]

var value = pieChart.getDataTable().getValue(pieChart.getView().rows[selectedItem.row], 1);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would one get the value if there is a view applied (e.g. filtered view)?